# Sitemap with pages missing better than no sitemap at all?

Tags: sitemap

I've inherited a site built with a CMS I'm not familiar with. I've created new pages for the site and I can see they do appear in a html sitemap, but not the xml sitemap.

Assuming I can't add the pages to the xml sitemap, should I delete the xml sitemap or leave it in place but with pages missing?

Comment: Feel free to put another question on this site about getting that sitemap to work. We'll need details of the CMS obviously.

Comment: Thanks for the offer. Im sure ill figure it out but its not my top priority at the moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Leave it in place, but ideally figure out how to add the missing pages eventually, if only for the sake of completeness. Sitemaps are only informative. If something is *missing* from the map, it won't be interpreted as "this isn't intended for crawling." As long as the pages are linked from *somewhere*, they'll get crawled.

You didn't mention how long you've given this, but note that generating a sitemap might be computationally expensive if it's a large site, so there might be a delay in regenerating it, either just from the process running, or even because there's a scheduled task that handles it rather than it being done real-time.